# Proving that $C_X$ is discrete if $X$ is discrete too.

Tags: real-analysis

If $X$ is discrete, I want to prove that then $(\mathcal C_X,d_H)$ is discrete, where $$C_X=\{\text{non empty compact subsets of X}\}$$ and

$$d_H(A, B) = \inf\{ \epsilon > 0: A \subset U_{\epsilon}(B),\ \ B\subset U_\epsilon(A)\}.$$

$$U_{\epsilon}(A)=\{x\in X: d(x,A)<\epsilon\}$$

Then, since $X$ is discrete we can provide it with the discrete metric,now, we need to prove that given a set $A \in C_X$ we need to give a neighborhood of $A$ such that the only set there is in fact $A$, but how can I proceed with the proof? because the definition of the set $U_{\epsilon}$ and $d_H$ with the discrete metric is confusing.

Can someone help me to prove this ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Note that compact set in a discrete space must be finite.

Comment: Right, the only sets in $C_X$ are singletons or finite union of them, but how can I find a radius of a open ball ,( in the case of tje union), that works to have onlty that ser in that ball :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a nonempty compact set in $X$. Then as $X$ is discrete, $A$ is finite. Let $x\in A$. Then as $X$ is discrete, there is $r_x>0$ so that $B_x(r_x)$ contains only $x$. Now let 
$$r_A = \min_{x\in A} r_x.$$
Then $r_A>0$ as $A$ is finite. Note for all $\epsilon <r_A$, we have $U_\epsilon A = A$. So if $B \subset U_r(A)$, then $B\subset A$. If $A\neq B$, then $A$ is not contained in $U_\epsilon B$, as $r_B \ge r_A$. So if

$$d_H (A, B)< r_A/2\Rightarrow A = B.$$
That is, there is a ball $B_{r_A/2}(A)$ in $C_X$ that contains only $A$. Thus $C_X$ is discrete.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMa :), what about this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483163/prove-that-a-sequence-converges-in-mathcalc

Comment: I'll take a look ^^. (Aside: It seems that you don't accept answer often. Note that accepting answer not only show your support to the answer-er, but is also a measure of usefulness of the site. Also, if someone sees an accepted answer, probably they don't have to click into the post and that save their time. (I am not surging you to accept the answer, I understand that different people holds different standards))

Comment: jajajaja, no, is not that, I don't accept answers until they are complete, this is I get a really answer, and in this case we must observe that the proof is complete an well perfomed, so I accept your answer :) that are my standards, otherwise if I accept an answer where I still have questions no one will take a look and provide an answer :) as it happens with other of my questions :)

Comment: Have you take a look @JohnMa ? Thnks :)